# pyspark - read individual file name within tsv.gz

Tags: pyspark

I want to be able to read individual files within tsv.gz from qubole s3 bucket

the following code i used the following for pyspark

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('QA test gzip files').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

with zipfile.ZipFile('s3://qubole-test/sample_test.tsv.gv') as file_name:
for n in file_name:
print(n)

It gave me an error. please help me

Comment: will you be able to share the error message ?

Comment: The error shows as follow "IOError: [Errno 2]: no such file or directory"

Comment: I just want to be able to identify if there are duplicate files within a zipfile